# Positioning images in a row with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd like to position **a bunch of images** next to each other (4 in a row), putting the 5th in the next line...

the image-width should be 1/4 of the row.

I'm trying to find a solution to that with flex-boxes, but no clue...

```html
<h2>Students</h2>
<div class="content">
  <img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
  <img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
  <img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
  <img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
  <img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
  <img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
  <img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason for needing to use flex when this can work without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.content > div {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content > div  img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Students</h2>
<div class="content">
  <div><img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
  <div><img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
  <div><img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
  <div><img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
  <div><img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
</div>
```

this is what you wanted?

Comment: not exactly... they shouldnt be vertically stretched

Comment: hmm, yep, weird, let me check what happend

Comment: img elemnt inside flex container loosing it's ratio so I would suggest going with div container for img

Comment: I fixed code snippet - I would suggest you to go with div with img inside as in my snippet :)

Comment: thanks that looks right! now adding space (margin between images) !?!

Answer (score 1):

You can set a static `width` and eventually a `margin` , all together, it should not exceed `25%` if you want 4 in a row, 33.33% for three in a row and so on .

```css
.content {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-items:flex-start; /* else image aare stretching in Chrome */
  }
.student {
  margin:1vw 1%;
  width:23%;/* 23% + 1% margin-left + 1% margin-right = 25% */
  }
```

```html
<h2>Students</h2>
<div class="content">
  <img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
  <img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
  <img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
  <img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
  <img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
  <img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
  <img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
</div>
```

**edit**
obviously, chrome is having issues **if**  `align-items:flex-start;` **is not set**,

... makes me think that `float` is cross browsers for this simple kind of layout:

```css
.content {
  overflow:hidden;
  }
.student {
  float:left;
  margin: 1%;
  width:23%;/* 23% + 1% margin-left + 1% margin-right = 25% */
  }
```

```html
<h2>Students</h2>
<div class="content">
  <img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
  <img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
  <img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
  <img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
  <img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
  <img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
  <img class="student" src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
</div>
```

Just saying :)